# Validating user input is valid number or not [invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*']

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, c++98

Ok so I am a  beginner in c/c++ and I am creating this little program that checks if the input provided by user is valid number or not, if it is then it prints " it is a number" or else it prints "it is a character string"

Some example output

```
1 - is a number
-1.1 - is a number
1......1 - is a character string
three - is a character string
.12 is a character string
+0.12 is a number
ABC123ABC - is a character string
```

I'm getting this error in my code. If someone could help me fix this I would really appreciate it. TIA

**cpp:52:23: error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]**

**if (!isNum(c[i]))**

**{
                    ~~~^
task1.cpp:5:19: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'bool isNum(char*)'
 bool isNum(char * p){**

**My code**

```
#include <iostream>



bool isNum(char * p){
if (NULL == p || *p == '\0'){
    return false;
}
int dot = 0;
int plus = 0;
int minus = 0;

while(*p){
    char a = *p;
    switch (a)
    {
        //Only allows 1 dot
        case '.':
            if (++dot > 1){
                return false;
            }
            break;
        //only allows 1 plus sign
        case '+':
            if (++plus > 1){
                return false;
            }
        //only allows 1 minus sign
        case '-':
            if (++minus > 1){
                return false;
            }
        //Only allows 0-9
        default:
            if (a < '0' || a > '9'){
                return false;
            }

       }
        p++;
    }
    return true;
}

int main(){
    //char array of size 1024
    char c[1024];
    std::cout << "Enter something: ";
    std::cin >> c;

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(c); i++){
        if (!isNum(c[i])){
            std::cout << c << " is a character string";    
        }
        else {
            std::cout << c << " is a number";
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: you function takes a char* &  you are passing a char

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this so can you help me fix this?

Comment: Better read a [book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), will save a ton of time (seriously).

Comment: I will look at this. Thank you

Comment: @JohnCasey Your code would be easier to understand if you documented it. For example, the `isNum` has no documentation on what it takes as input, which likely lead you to call it with the wrong input. if it had documentation that said something like "input `p` is a pointer to the character to test" then you'd know that you needed to pass it a pointer to the character to test. Without at least such a comment, you can easily pass a function the wrong thing.

Comment: It is recommended to decide what language you are beginner with, C or C++. Trying to learn both at the same time could be frustrating and counterproductive.

Answer (score 1):

There you go, i've commented the things i had changed

```
#include <iostream>             
bool isNum(char * p) {
    if (NULL == p || *p == '\0') {
        return false;
    }
    int dot = 0;

    char a = *p;
    if (a<'0' || a>'9') {
        if (a != '-' && a != '+') { return false; }
        else p++;

    }


    if (*p<'0' || *p>'9') return false;
    p++;
    while (*p != '\0') {
        a = *p;
        switch (a)
        {
            //Only allows 1 dot
        case '.':
            if (++dot > 1) {
                return false;
            }
            p++;
            if (*p == '\0') return false;
            break;

        default:
            if (a < '0' || a > '9') {
                return false;
            }
            p++;
            break;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

    int main() {
        //char array of size 1024
        char c[1024];
        std::cout << "Enter something: ";
        std::cin >> c;

        // you don't need to loop through every character just pass your array of characters & your function is looping through it
        if (!isNum(c)) {
            std::cout << c << " is a character string";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << c << " is a number";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hey for some reason this is counting all numbers with negative and positive in front as a character string any idea why?

Comment: Also .1 is getting counted as number it should be char string

Comment: You forgot to "break" after the cases so its getting to the default anyway

Comment: I added break for each cases and it's still doing the same

Comment: you should check that the first char is + or - or a number but not a dot

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much

Comment: i'm gonna leave the correct answer here for future reference but i hope you do it yourself

Comment: For some reason it returns + and - as a number

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187373/discussion-between-john-casey-and-spinkoo).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to practice complicated algorithms, parsing numbers is a good exercise. But if your goal is to write useful, simple programs, you are on the wrong track. In C++, many common tasks are already solved by the C++ standard library, you just have to use them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string line;

    if (!std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
        std::cerr << "error reading the line\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::istringstream in{line};
    double num;

    if (in >> num && in.peek() == EOF) {
        std::cout << "it's a number, " << num << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "it's not a number\n";
    }
}
```

The above code reads more high-level than your code. Most importantly it can handle arbitrary long lines without crashing the program.

I'm not intimately familiar with the C++ headers, so I may have forgotten to include some others. But the rest of the code should be ok, even though I didn't test it.

Answer (score 1):

The following function `isNumber` would work for you.

- Here I use a dynamic character sequence `std::string` which enables us to input any size strings less shorter than `std::string::max_size`.
- We can check whether a given character is a digit or not by [`std::isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit).
- No extra copies and object creation would show good performance.
- Whitespace characters are not allowed in the left and right side of the input string.

I also write the explicit type of the iterators and avoid using `auto` because you are tagging `C++98`:

```
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

bool isNumber(const std::string& s)
{
    // this also validates the following access to s[0]
    if(s.empty()){
        return false;
    }

    const std::size_t offset = (s[0] == '+' || s[0] == '-') ? 1 : 0;
    std::string::const_iterator begin = s.begin() + offset;

    // this also validates the following dereferencing begin
    if(begin == s.end()){
        return false; // false if just a sign "+" or "-"
    }

    if(!std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(*begin))){
        return false; // e.g. "+.123"
    }

    bool isdecimal = false;
    for(std::string::const_iterator it = ++begin; it != s.end(); ++it) 
    {
        if (!std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(*it)))
        {
            if(!isdecimal && (*it == '.'))
            {
                isdecimal = true;

                if((it+1) == s.end()){
                    return false; // e.g. "+1."
                }
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

---

Now it is easy and straightforward to implement the main function:

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uuw1DzPwp9kVUtxe)

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string s;

    std::cout << "Enter something: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout 
        << s << " is a " 
        << (isNumber(s) ? "number." : "character string.");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Spinkoo's code meets all the requirements I'm using but for some reason it's printing + and - as a number. Any idea why?

Comment: @JohnCasey He fixed the behavior of his code after his last comment. In that version, it would print `+` and `-` as a characters, but it would still print `+1.` as a number, I think. But what's wrong with my answer ? :) Could you please check my [**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uuw1DzPwp9kVUtxe) linked in my answer description.

Comment: I have to use a char array which stores user input in it

Comment: @JohnCasey Hmm... there are no needs to use a C-style `char` array to do it in C++. `std::string::data` returns `char*` or `const char*`, and `std::string::size` returns it's size. You can also edit it using various public methods. Then, why you use C++?

Comment: I'm taking an OS class where we have really old os system we are using and it only uses old fashioned c and c++98

Comment: @JohnCasey Okay, I see. I don’t know the details, but I hope you will go well! :)